# Clashing classes in CSS and inherited properties

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently added bootstrap to my project and it works great but I've run into a CSS issue.

Prior to adding bootstrap to my project, I add the following CSS class:

```
        .inlineItem.label {
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-right: 20px;
            width: 220px;
        }
```

Bootstrap has its own .label

```
.label {
       display: inline;
       padding: .2em .6em .3em;
       font-size: 75%;
       font-weight: 700;
       line-height: 1;
       color: #fff;
       text-align: center;
       white-space: nowrap;
       vertical-align: baseline;
       border-radius: .25em;
      }
```

I figured no problem, my class and where I want it to apply is more specific than the bootstrap class so it will just ignore it. The problem is it still took the bootstrap label class and just added the other properties from the more specific one.

I assume this is how CSS is supposed to work.

Other than renaming my class or setting the properties that might be overridden by the bootstrap label class as inherit, is there no way to tell it not to use the class from Bootstrap library?

Comment: Just change YOUR `.label`.

Comment: Change the your .label class to .mylabel  and try..

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you are declaring bootstrap BEFORE you .css file:

```
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/yourstylefile.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If you do it, you should try to delete label style from bootstrap.css (is easy) or change label style in your .css file.

```
.label {
       display: inherit;
       padding: inherit;
       font-size: inherit;
       font-weight: inherit;
       line-height: inherit;
       color: inherit;
       text-align: inherit;
       white-space: inherit;
       vertical-align: inherit;
       border-radius: inherit;
}
```